# add values in custom dataType Fields

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to create and [custom datatype](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#custom_data_types) and add value in it.

I have created 2 fields successfully, I am getting in call back. My code is

```
    // Subscribe to some data sources!
                            DataTypeCreateRequest  request = new DataTypeCreateRequest.Builder()
                                    // The prefix of your data type name must match your app's package name
                                    .setName("com.fitnessapi.data_type")
                                            // Add some custom fields, both int and float
                                    .addField("one", Field.FORMAT_FLOAT)
                                    .addField("two", Field.FORMAT_FLOAT)
                                    .addField(Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY)
                                    .build();



                            PendingResult<DataTypeResult> pendingResult = Fitness.ConfigApi.createCustomDataType(mClient, request);
                            request.


                            pendingResult.setResultCallback(
                                    new ResultCallback<DataTypeResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResult(DataTypeResult dataTypeResult) {
                                            // Retrieve the created data type
                                            DataType customType = dataTypeResult.getDataType();
                                            System.out.println("one two" + customType.toString());


                                        }
                                    }
                            );

                            // [START auth_build_googleapiclient_ending]
                        }
```

I am not able to find any method to fill values in these 2 fields.

Answer (score 5):

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#custom_data_types) on this are light on working details.  Below is a working example.

Let's start with writing some custom data, I am going to make a field called flightcount (as in flights of stairs the user has climbed during a session), it is an int.

I put this code where my FitnessClient triggers the onConnected callback.  Note that I store the datatype as a member variable mCustomType, we will need that later:

```
    DataTypeCreateRequest request = new DataTypeCreateRequest.Builder()
        // The prefix of your data type name must match your app's package name
        .setName("com.digitalconstruction.flightthepower.flights")
                // Add a custom field
        .addField("flightcount", Field.FORMAT_INT32)
                // Add some common fields
        .addField(Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY)
        .build();


PendingResult<DataTypeResult> pendingResult =
        Fitness.ConfigApi.createCustomDataType(mClient, request);


pendingResult.setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<DataTypeResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DataTypeResult dataTypeResult) {
        // Retrieve the created data type
        mCustomType = dataTypeResult.getDataType();
    }
}
```

);

Inserting a dataset is fairly trivial but creating the custom dataset was not, so here is sample code of that.  Make a datasource, then a dataset, then a datapoint.  Pay careful attention to the datapoint creation, its different than the Google sample code which won't even compile:

```
        // Create a data source
    DataSource climbDataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(this.getPackageName())
            .setDataType(mCustomType)
            .setName(SAMPLE_SESSION_NAME)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    // Create a data set of the climb flight count to include in the session.
    DataSet climbDataSet = DataSet.create(climbDataSource);

    // Create a data point for a data source that provides
    DataPoint dataPoint = DataPoint.create(climbDataSource);

    // Set values for the data point
    // This data type has one custom fields (int) and a common field
    //tricky way to set single int
    dataPoint.getValue(mCustomType.getFields().get(0)).setInt(8);
    dataPoint.setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    //tricky way to set activity, not at all how the non-working google sample code is set up
    FitnessActivities.setValue(dataPoint, FitnessActivities.STAIR_CLIMBING);

    climbDataSet.add(dataPoint);
```

Finally we want to read this data, the method dumpDataSet can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history).

```
//read custom data type: mCustomType
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        cal.setTime(now);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        final DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .read(mCustomType)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

        DataReadResult dataReadResult =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        dumpDataSet(dataReadResult.getDataSet(mCustomType));
```

And it works, here is some of the output:

03-06 12:52:30.445  31506-31746/com.digitalconstruction.flightthepower I/MARK﹕ Field: flightcount Value: 8

03-06 12:52:30.445  31506-31746/com.digitalconstruction.flightthepower I/MARK﹕ Field: activity Value: 77

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is your GoogleApi client configured because... I've used your code as a template for my own custom data object and... whilst the DataSet contains data, a query to the API reveals that nothing has been written to the API. Do you have to 'commit' the DataSet to the API?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too.

the doc says to use getVaule :

```
dataPoint.getValue(0).setInt(mField1IntValue);
```

The problem is the getVaule method wants a Field.
After playing around with it I found that you can get a list of Fields by:

```
dataSet.getDataType().getFields()
```

So to set your custom DateType Fields I am using this method.

```
dataPoint.getValue(dataSet.getDataType().getFields().get(0)).setInt(5);
```

No idea of this is right, or a dumb way of doing it but it works.

Comment: Now I am able to add the data successfully, but now not able to read it. Got method to read. but always it says Unset. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/ConfigApi.html